# Play Sound Using Javascript with UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I Have the below Asp.net Code:

the problem is that When Timer Tick Every 30 Second and GridView Filled the javascript code is not executed !! and Sound is not played.

I have also tried SoundPlayer Class but is not working on the Server Side can anyone provide me with a solution ?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="OrdersPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Orders_" Async="true" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Gazar | Orders Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowProgress() {
            document.getElementById('UpdateProgress1').style.display = "inline";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" class="center_it" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table class="MainTable">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left;" colspan="2">
                        <img id="Img2" src="~/images/gazzarlogo.png" alt="GazarBanner" runat="server" class="BannerImage" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="30pt" ForeColor="White"
                            Text="الطلبـــــات"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click1" Text="History" CssClass="Buttons" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Exit" Text="خروج" runat="server" OnClick="Exit_Click" CssClass="Buttons" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewOrders" runat="server" Style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
                            OnRowDataBound="GridViewOrders_RowDataBound" PageSize="30" BackColor="White"
                            BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" CaptionAlign="Top"
                            CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" EnableModelValidation="True"
                            GridLines="Vertical" Width="1100px" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="10pt" Font-Bold="False"
                            OnRowCommand="GridViewOrders_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" Wrap="True" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Open" ItemStyle-Width="60px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Button ID="ApproveBtn" Text="Open" Width="60" Height="30" runat="server" OnClientClick="ShowProgress()" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="70px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="70px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="OrderID" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="70px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Name" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" ItemStyle-Width="300px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Address" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Address") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="300px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Number" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Number") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sent Date" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="SentDate" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Sent Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Recieved Date" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="RecievedDate" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Recieved Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="# Success" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="SuccessNo" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "# Success") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="# Fake" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="FakeNo" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "# Fake") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Restaurant" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Restaurant" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Restaurant") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Branch" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Branch" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Branch") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="LoadingDiv">
                    <span class="LoadingLabel">Check Orders ...</span>
                    <img class="LoadingImg" src="Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading ..." />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="30000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and code behind is:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)

       {
            orderDB.LogState("Time Tick");
            if (Session["UserID"] != null)
            {
                orderDB.LogState("Session Alive");
                FillDataGrid(int.Parse(Session["UserID"].ToString()));
                orderDB.LogState("End fill Grid View");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
            }
        }

private void FillDataGrid(int UserID)
{

    Orders = orderDB.GetOrdersByUser(UserID);
    orderDB.LogState("Select: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\t" + Request.UserHostAddress + "\t" + Session.SessionID + "\t" + Session["UserID"].ToString());

    if (Orders == null)
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");

    DataTable Table = new DataTable();

    Table.Columns.Add("ID", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    Table.Columns.Add("Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    Table.Columns.Add("Address", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    Table.Columns.Add("Number", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    Table.Columns.Add("Sent Date", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    Table.Columns.Add("Recieved Date", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    Table.Columns.Add("# Success", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    Table.Columns.Add("# Fake", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    Table.Columns.Add("Restaurant", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    Table.Columns.Add("Branch", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

    for (int i = 0; i < Orders.Count; i++)
    {
        object[] myRow = new object[10];
        myRow[0] = Orders[i].GetId();
        myRow[1] = Orders[i].GetOwner();
        myRow[2] = Orders[i].GetAddress().getAllAddress();
        myRow[3] = Orders[i].GetPhoneNumber();
        myRow[4] = Orders[i].GetOriginalTime().ToString();
        myRow[5] = Orders[i].GetTime().ToString();
        myRow[6] = Orders[i].NoOfSuccess; //success Orders;
        myRow[7] = Orders[i].NoOfFake; //fake Orders
        myRow[8] = Orders[i].GetResName();
        myRow[9] = Orders[i].GetBranchName();

        Table.Rows.Add(myRow);
    }

    orderDB.LogState("Table Rows Count: " + Table.Rows.Count);
    GridViewOrders.DataSource = Table;
    GridViewOrders.DataBind();

    string sSelectedAudio = Server.MapPath("home.wav");
    if (GridViewOrders.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        playSound(sSelectedAudio);
        orderDB.LogState("Sound Played: " + GridViewOrders.Rows.Count);
    }
    else
    {
        orderDB.LogState("Empty Grid View: " + GridViewOrders.Rows.Count);
    }
}

private void playSound(string path)
{
    string PlaySound = "<embed src=\"" + path + "\" autostart=\"true\" hidden=\"true\"></embed>";
    Response.Write(PlaySound);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the `Response.Write` that's causing the issue. Try using a placeholder control then adding a `HtmlGenericControl` to it with the markup for the embed tag i.e.

```
 HtmlGenericControl sound = new HtmlGenericControl("<embed src=\"" + path + "\" 
           autostart=\"true\" hidden=\"true\"></embed>");
    ucPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(sound);
```

Make sure the placeholder control is withing the `ContentTemplate` of the UpdatePanel that you are using